# Is there a way to view comments on author-withdrawn questions?

Tags: support, comments, closed-questions, global-inbox

I down-voted a question based on the poster having asked the same question about 45 minutes prior. Following this, someone commented *something* about my downvote, but when I tried to view it, I could not because by then the poster had removed the dupe. All I can see are the first few characters in my 'inbox'. Is there a way to view historical activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless you are a 10K moderator.

Comment: 10K users can see deleted questions, including the comments made to a deleted question. But they cannot see deleted *comments*: only moderators can do that.